# What is DateParseException in android

Tags: android

What are DateParseException exceptions and what causes them?

What methods/tools can be used to determine the cause so that you stop the exception from causing the program to terminate prematurely? How can we use the LogCat to debug issues about this exception?

Comment: Are you parse any date in to `SimpleDateFormat`???

Comment: Logcat display the code in which you get the Exception. By seeing this code we identify what mistake we have done in our code. You should post your logcat message.I thinh DateParseException occured because you are not passing date in proper format.

Comment: quick search on google tells me that **it is a class derived from Exception class** ... in apache http client ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more about your application, where you're seeing this exception, when you're seeing this, etc... it is really difficult to even begin to answer the question.

The [documentation for DateParseException](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/cookie/DateParseException.html), however, indicates that it is from an apache library, and may be related to the [DateUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/cookie/DateUtils.html) class. That class is used to decode HTTP cookies, although both classes may be used for other things, of course.

If your app does network connections, probably using cookies, then this might be a good place to begin looking for the problem.